# How to load multiline JSON in spark with Java

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, multiline

I am looking for a way to load multiline JSON into Spark using Java.  The Spark `SQLContext` has methods to load JSON, but it only supports "one record per line".  I have a multiline JSON file that I need to process.

Example input:
The JSON contains words, definitions and example sentences :

```
{
"one-armedbandit": 
    [
        {
            "function": "noun",
            "definition": "slot machine",
            "examples": 
            [
            ]
        }
    ],
...
}
```

Comment: I have seen that if you have multiline JSON files, you will instead have to load the whole file and then parse each file.  Does that mean parsing the file as JSON using some library and then getting those JSON records into an RDD somehow?

Comment: Lets clear the terms:
Multiline json means that, a single json object has line breaks in it instead of being on a single line? Is there more than one json object in this file?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the content of the files? Single document, array of documents, something else?

Comment: @Dennis your definition of multiline is accurate.  There are more than one json objects in this file

Comment: How are these documents separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was read the JSON into a List of POJOs with a JSON processor, then called `parallelize` on the `SparkContext` to get a `JavaRDD`.

Answer (score 0):

The Spark ingestion methods indeed accept a [json-line format](http://jsonlines.org/). You could consider using a json processor to convert your data to this format before processing.

Comment: This requires fiddling with the original source which I was hoping not to have to do.